# How to specify which variable on which axis in Wolframalpha plot?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha

For example, I want to plot y=x^2, but I would like y to be the horizontal axis and x the vertical axis. Of course I could plot y=+-sqrt(x) and mentally change the variable names, but this will not be feasible for other examples.

Answer (score 2):

Wolfram Alpha is not known for it being particularly customizable. Part of what you're trying to achieve can be done by [calling](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ParametricPlot[%7Bx%5E2,x%7D])

```
ParametricPlot[{x^2,x}]
```

or, for [manual axes limits](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ParametricPlot[%7Bx%5E2,x%7D,%7Bx,-2,2%7D]),

```
ParametricPlot[{x^2,x},{x,-2,2}]
```

These will flip the axes for you, without you having to invert your function manually, which is one of your major obstacles.

Unfortunately I couldn't get WA to add axes labels to your needs. For reference, the corresponding command in Mathematica would be

```
ParametricPlot[{x^2,x},{x,-2,2},AxesLabel->{y,x}]
```

but note that in Mathematica you can't use automatic axes limits, you have to be explicit.